# onclick method doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This code works in Mozilla Firefox, but not in Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "response1.php"
    document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window

    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page

    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "response2.php"
    document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window

    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page

    return true;
}
-->
</script>
<noscript>You need Javascript enabled for this to work</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Form1" method="post">
Your Name <input type="text" name="name" size="10" /><br />
<INPUT type="button" value="Button1" name=name onclick="OnButton2();OnButton1();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What can we use in the place of `onclick` to trigger the two actions?

Comment: instead of calling 2 functions on button click; call one after other!

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Comment: Wring syntax : `document.Form1.action`, `<script language="Javascript">`, `<!--`

Comment: I suspect Chrome just has better protection against sites spamming multiple windows at the user and that you can't work around it.

Comment: It's actually possible in Chrome too if you add little timeout in the second submission.

Comment: @dfsq. Can you explain how ?

Comment: @NBSriHarsha http://plnkr.co/edit/yYxGhj1kgR9uJEXoKfFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dfsq for providing the answer !

It's actually possible in Chrome too if you add little timeout in the second submission

```
<html>

<head>
    <script language="Javascript">
        <!--
        function OnButton1() {
            document.Form1.action = "response1.php"
            document.Form1.target = "_blank";
            document.Form1.submit();
        }

        function OnButton2() {
            document.Form1.action = "response2.php"
            document.Form1.target = "_blank";
            document.Form1.submit();
        }
         -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need Javascript enabled for this to work</noscript>
    <form name="Form1" method="post">
        Your Name
        <input type="text" name="name" size="10" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Button1" name="name" onclick="OnButton1();setTimeout(OnButton2, 50)">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

**HTML button :**

```
<input type="button" value="Button1" name="name" onclick="return OnButton1();">
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "response1.php"
    document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window

    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page

    OnButton2();                        //Calling second function here
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "response2.php"
    document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window

    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why would moving the call to `OnButton2` from after the call to `OnButton1` to the end of `OnButton1` help?

Comment: calling `return OnButton1();` on button click; will surely help!

Comment: Why would it help? The return value isn't being used for anything.

Comment: Of course it won't make any difference. You are missing the point of the question I think, which is making a form submit to 2 actions at once. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome. Anyway, here is a demo of your code, which proves that it is not working. http://plnkr.co/edit/yYxGhj1kgR9uJEXoKfFV?p=preview

Comment: still it doesnt work in chrome ! 

check this >> http://abitech.com.au/check2.php